# Property `_statusBarTintColorLockingControllers` at `UIApplication` keeping ViewController in memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode8

Using Xcode 8 new memory debugger I found out there was a ViewController in memory that shouldn't be there and the strong reference that was pointing to it was coming from this mysterious `_statusBarTintColorLockingControllers` array in UIApplication. Does anybody know where it comes from? And more importantly, how to take my VC out of it?

[image: memory debugger]

Comment: Did you sort this out? Seeing the exact same pattern in an application built with iOS 10 SDK.

Comment: Did you try setting `networkClient` on `ExamsWebCollection` to `nil`?

Answer (score 4):

`_statusBarTintColorLockingControllers` seems not to be the real issue here. I had the same memory graph until I resolved a retain cycle where I forgot `weak` on a delegate property.

Comment: Same here. Mine was hidden amongst two other delegate declarations, so it took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Agreed! XCode messes up here a bit, pointing to _statusBarTintColorLockingControllers. There is actually some other subtle memory issue that needs to be resolved. Once that issue is resolved, the cycle is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with same problem when forgot to set some property to nil before dismiss my controller

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it looks like this comes from overriding the `preferredStatusBarStyle` variables. I removed this and no longer had the references retained.